# smart way remove class in list ul-li when reload data for li in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I have a list with data. When I click reload, only the data changes, it does not load all of the page (good).

But the html and css are not reloaded, the same default.

I want to load the same default without [for] and [remove] in item ...

Please tell me a more ... smart way?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please paste your code here,

Comment: I can't copy, it very munch

Comment: Can you make a fiddle then ?
Because it's not pretty much clear what you are asking.

Comment: thanks @WasifAli , I fix it with the way I think is smart. lol